# How to test for a non--zero rational function?

Tags: functions, algebra

I want to test if a rational function in one variable is identically zero. I was surprised that just writing `f==0` doesn't do it.  I wrote the following code:

```
MyZeroTest[f_, z_] := Module[{floc},  
floc = Numerator[ Together[f]];  
CoefficientList[floc, z] == {}   
];
```

This seems to work, but I feel I must be reinventing the wheel.  Isn't there a built--in method?

Remarks:  There is some ambiguity in the term "rational function".  I mean an element of the field $\mathbb Q(z)$, so in Mathematica, an expression like `f = 1/(z^2 + 2 z - 2) + (z - 4)/(z^5 + 4)`, and not a function like `f[z_] = 1/(z^2 + 2 z - 2) + (z - 4)/(z^5 + 4)`.  I am interested in knowing if the element is "identically zero", i.e. zero as an element of $\mathbb Q(z)$.

I have received the suggestions to try `FullSimplfy[f==0]` or `Reduce[f==0]` or `PossibleZeroQ[f]`.

With the example `f = 1/(z^2 + 2 z - 2) + (z - 4)/(z^5 + 4)`, `FullSimplfy[f==0]` simply fails,  `Reduce[f==0]` attempts to find complex roots of the equation, which is not what I am looking for, and
`PossibleZeroQ[f]` apparently does what I want, namely determines whether the expression is identically zero.

Comment: `PossibleZeroQ[f]`. Or `FullSimplify[f==0]`

Comment: Did you try `Reduce[f[x] == 0]` or `Simplify[f[x] == 0]`.

Comment: Some examples would be appropriate.

Comment: I have clarified the question, given an example, and identified the suggestion to use `PossibleZeroQ[f]` as a correct answer.